# Effective way for creating Open Source Web mapping applications

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, geoext

Sorry for asking such a basic question, but these days there is lot of advancement on open source technologies.

My requirements for my application are below

1. Basic Map application with zoom, pan, etc
2. Dynamic Attribute Query based on the Layer selected on TOC
3. Input Data is from mostly Shape files / PostGIS

I know about GeoServer + GeoEXT or MapServer + Fusion or any other alternative if so please suggest

But need advice from real programmers for extending the application in further and also wanted to know best open source web mapping practice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum.I think your question has lots of dimensions so according to me please go though similar questions http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping/8147#8147 ,http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18802/where-to-start-with-web-gis-development-or-which-technology-to-select

Comment: Thank you Sunil but as I already said there are too many frameworks, So I have myselft put down into 2 as mentioned above. So wanted to know which one is effective like extending with more custom controls on map later

Comment: I am using Open layers/Map box/leaflet +geoserver + postGIS +QGIS (as Desktop GIS)